# Eclipselink JPA - String attribute mapped to Xml type column

Tags: xml, jpa, reference, java-8, eclipselink

I have a String attribute which is mapped to an xml type column in DB2 :

```
@Column(name = "SEARCH_CRITERIA", nullable = false)
private String searchCriteria;
```

EclipseLink returns a reference : com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.re@8cc92e26

Before, I used openJPA which returned exactly what i wanted :

```
"<person>
<name>John</name>
<age>30</age>
<job/>
</person>"
```

How can I tell eclipselink to return a String like openJPA does ?
Thank you !

(Java 8, JPA 2.1, Websphere 9)

Answer (score 0):

What version of WAS are you using?
There is a PMR opened on a similar subject: [PI76834](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI76834)
Its is fixed in WAS v9.0.0.4 and WLP v17.0.0.2

Comment: Hi, thanks for your concern !
I'm actually using WAS 9.0.0.4 (
9.0.0.4-WS-WAS-IFPI86053 9.0.4.20170829_1329), seems like EclipseLink version was affected too.

In any case, the reported issue says a null is returned specially on J2e 6. I do receive a non null object.

For now i found a workaround, which is serializing the xml column XMLSERIALIZE(xml_column as varchar(1000)). It's working fine but as said, it's a workaround.

Comment: You didn't mention your EclipseLink version - the associated bug says it was fixed in 2.6.1. If you can, check the getStringAndFreeSQLXML method within the JDK16Platform class and that it is getting called - this is what should convert the type to a string.